# How to place a button on animation image in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

In my app, I have an array of image, which is getting animated for every second.
I used the following code,

```
 animateArrayImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"gallery-img-1.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"gallery-img-2.png"],nil];
animateImageView.animationImages = animateArrayImages;
animateImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animateImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animateImageView startAnimating];
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

But I am getting an output like this
[image]
The button is getting displayed in the background of the image.
But I want to display it befor the image

Comment: Use **insertSubview:aboveSubview:** or call **addSubview:button** after **addSubview:animateImageView**

Comment: Its fine still your touch even will work. Look if you have an image view in xib then manually add button out there and also programmatically you can set the frame of button similar to image view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bring the button on top of the image, you can call the following method after `addSubview:`

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```